# Unique ID (UUID) changes on iOS Widget and not on React Native app

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, uuid, today-extension

I am developing an application in React Native, this one is connected to an API where I send and retrieve user-specific data. So I use a unique ID: **UUID**

I need this unique ID, because it allows me to retrieve the user's own data and display it on a **Today Extension** (Widget iOS).

To retrieve this ID I use the `react-native-device-info` library for the app in React Native and `let UUID = UIDevice.current.identifyForVendor?.uuidString` in Swift

However during the tests and after deployment, I noticed that this unique ID changes for the widget on some devices. This unlinks the application and widget and makes the data exchange null or false.

Does anyone know how it would be possible to get the UUID generated by the application into the Widget via a bridge? **If yes how can I do this bridge?**

Or if there is another unique ID that I could use? I have seen the IDFA during my research, would it be better to use it even if I don't use ads on my app.

Thank you in advance

Comment: if user disable Limit Ad tracking options then you won't get IDFA. so it is better to use identifierForVendor. Whenever we ask for uuid from UIDevice.current.identifyForVendor?.uuidString you will get new value so once you get the uuid in native code don't again ask in react native or vice versa, so use the same one by passing it .

Comment: The IDFA brings its own headaches by complicating the Apple review process. If you do end up using IDFA, make sure to confirm you're using it when you submit your app for review, otherwise Apple will permanently reject your  app.

Comment: @Sumeet.Jain thx for the precisions. Do you know a way for passing the data from the app to the today widget ?

Comment: @AnonymousSB yeah I saw it when I deployed the app on the apple store, they use to ask if the app is using the IDFA.

Comment: @Jeremovich You can use shared UserDefaults to share data between App Extension and its Host App with the help of App Group, i.e. a shared container UserDefaults(suiteName:) to share data.                                                          
For more, refer to: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1

How to use App Groups: https://github.com/pgpt10/Today-Widget